# Ошибка: Не удалось создать imagesource на основе текста

Tags: c#, wpf

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Images.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="RecStartButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="67" Click="RecStart"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="FindedSong" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="172,174,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312"/>
        <Image x:Name="FindedSongPicture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="45,174,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Images.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ImageSource x:Key="NoAlbum">Resources/NoAlbum.png</ImageSource>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Вставляю картинку в Image:

```
FindedSongPicture.Source = (ImageSource)FindResource("NoAlbum");
```

Получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Comment: У меня всё работает (ц). Может, вы неправильно вставили картинку? Какой у вас Build Action для неё?

Comment: Cначала не было, потом поставил Resource, в обоих случаях не работает

Comment: Перепроверьте, может быть вы неправильно указали путь к ресурсу? У меня получается такое же сообщение об ошибке, если я делаю опечатку в пути.

Comment: Может, где-то русская буква вместо английской?

Comment: я создал картинку при помощи графического редактора в Visual Studio. Прямо в ресурсах, и она автоматически там оказалась, когда я прописываю Resources/NoAlbum.png её название всплывает в подсказке, наличие русских букв исключено

Comment: У меня точно такой же код работает. Только картинку я взял из интернета. Хм. Пишите воспроизводящий проблему тест.

Comment: Да, а какая у вас Студия?

Comment: 2013, с картинкой из произвольной папки тоже не работает

Comment: Ага, с 2013-ой студией воспроизвелось :) Сейчас соображу, как исправить. С 2015-ой проблем нет.

Comment: Окей, пробуйте так: `<BitmapImage x:Key="NoAlbum" UriSource="Resources/NoAlbum.png"/>`. У меня в 2013 так взлетело.

Comment: Да, всё заработало, спасибо огромное, добрый человек

Comment: Окей, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Visual Studio 2015 такой код, как в вопросе, прекрасно работает.

Для Visual Studio 2013 нужно немного подсказать фреймворку:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="NoAlbum" UriSource="Resources/NoAlbum.png"/>
```